# Why my books not arranged in correct shelves (React-Redux)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am creating a book tracking app that fetches books by ajax and organize them on shelves, i have many components but i have a problem that exists between two of them, AllShelves, and BookShelf, i am so confused, the shelf titles is rendered in the correct order as in shelves array, my problem starts when i try to arrange books on their corresponding shelves, i need shelfName to do that, i filtered my books in mapStateToProps but i ended with books in wrong shelves, when i console logged shelfName in mapStateToProps i got this order

```
//read
//currentlyReading
//wantToRead
```

instead of

```
//currentlyReading
//wantToRead
//read
```

and even duplicated

These are my components

The first component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BookShelf from './BookShelf'

const AllShelves = () => {

   const shelves = [
    {
      title: 'Currently Reading',
      shelfName: 'currentlyReading'
    },
    {
      title: 'Want to read',
      shelfName: 'wantToRead'
    }, 
    {
      title:'Read',
      shelfName: 'read'
    }
  ];

  return(
   <div>
    {shelves.map((shelf, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="shelf" key={index}>
          <h2>{shelf.title}</h2>
          <BookShelf 
            shelfName={shelf.shelfName}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
 );
} 

export default AllShelves;
```

The child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Book from './Book'
import {connect } from 'react-redux';


let shelfName = '';

const BookShelf = (props) => {

  shelfName = props.shelfName;

  return(
    <div className="book-shelf">
       {props.books.map(book => (
          <Book 
            key={book.id}
            book={book}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
 }

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(shelfName)//read
                        //currentlyReading
                        //wantToRead
  return {
    books: state.filter(book => book.shelf === shelfName)
 }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(BookShelf);
```

So what is the problem here, why not shelfName items not logged in correct order like titles.

Comment: Your books arrray will likely be sorted differently than your shelves that happens when you filter the array in mapstatetorops.

Comment: @misraX yes this is obvious, but why this happens?

Comment: @Nguyễn Thanh Tú i think this is not the case here, i have one reducer that returns an array of books objects after sending 'FETCH_BOOKS' action, i a m trying to filter the books to send each to its corresponding shelf

Comment: @SaherElgendy I provide an answer with working example. The unexpected behavior comes from the way you use to retrieve the value of `shelfName` property inside the `mapStateToProps()` function.

Comment: As I said the book array is sorted differently that causes a different sorted array of filtered data in your mapStateToProps. Try to sort your book array first if u want your arrays to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (I simplify some codes and focus on the main problem we need to solve)

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const BookShelf = props => {
  const shelfName = props.shelfName;
  return <div>{shelfName}</div>;
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(ownProps.shelfName);
  return ({

  });
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookShelf);
```

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/p5jr57vw8j

[image: demo]

If you want to access the passed properties inside the `mapStateToProps()` function, doing it this way. For more information, you could find it here: [mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: This works, your solution also makes my code git rid of the global variable..but do you have an idea why my code returned the wrong order??@Nguyễn Thanh Tú